# is it possible to mix jquery and template literal like this?

Tags: jquery, find, append, template-literals

Im trying to inject 1 jQuery object too another,
using find(), and append().
but something goes wrong and I'm not sure why?

http://codepen.io/ueeieei/pen/RoyVGB?editors=0010

my code:

```
//template
var $container = $(`
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>  
`);

//DOM ingridients
var $header = $(`<h1>Main Title</h1>`);
var $content = $(`<p>asldalsdkjaflskdfjsldkfjsdlfksj</p>`);

// Calling the function that do all
$('body').append(doIt($container, $header));


// the glue that binds all
function doIt($template, $headerContent){
    $('body').append($template);
    $container.find('.header').append($headerContent);
}
```

Comment: Apparently `find` only works when you have a single root element: wrapping your template into another element like this: `$container = $("<div> ... </div>")` starts you moving. There's other errors remaining, I believe, but I don't quite know what you want to do. Also, you are using template string literals needlessly - just because they're called template string literals, doesn't mean you need them when building a templating system.

Comment: I dont think its true that find() is working only on single root elements.
my teacher in class did it on bigger elements, and that is where I got the idea from. also the string literal.
https://github.com/roypeled/EMS-sample/blob/master/src/Item.es6